# CSS reference failure in express: why and how to fix?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express

Here's a simple express server I have:

```
// a small demo to exercise
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyparser = require("body-parser");

app.use("/public/", express.static("./public/"));
app.use("/node_modules/",express("./node_modules/"));
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyparser.json());
//app.set
app.engine("html", require("express-art-template"));
app.get("/index", function (request, response) {
    response.render("index.html");
});
app.listen(9000, function () {
    console.log("server is running!!");
});
```

I've got a problem with CSS. The below picture illustrates it:
[image]

Here is my index.html:
[image]

Here is my resources folders:
[image]

I've searched a lot but failed to fix it. How do I do that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please improve your post so that others become more willing to answer: substitute your picture of html with actual html, screenshot of error with its text and description (when you see it, what's the expected behaviour, what is the actual one). The picture of your folders structure should be substituted with text as well (or even removed since you probably need only to show the path to the CSS and html). Best regards

Comment: I am very sorry.Your advice is very good.But you konw that my english isn't good.It takes me a lot of time to edit a problem.....but the quality of the problem isn’t perfect

Comment: No problem, just edit your question and insert code instead of pictures. And don't forget to accept your answer if you have fixed the issue (this will be possible a day later, though) – so that it's clear that it's solved

Comment: I get it!Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a foolish mistake.

app.use("/node_modules",express.static("./node_modules"));